# Where should I put utility method to parse PLIST file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

(relatively new ios developer)

I am building a drill-down table and the data is read from a plist file. Initially data was a Dictionary at the root of the plist but needed order to be maintained.

It's now an array, but at the expense of needing some additional formatting to extract the data.

There are 2 view controllers (Master/Detail) that would need to access this method.

There are 2 options i'm thinking about but I am unsure which to implement:

1. Create a utility class where Class helper methods can go
   Is it okay to have a class that contains a mixed bag of methods for utility use?
2. Create a Category on the ViewController. This category would only be used by 2 view controllers and there would only be 1 method in the category.

I would like to learn if there are better practices out there for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a "model" class that knows how to process and provide the data.

Answer (score 0):

This may be answering a more general question than you are asking but: if you have not come across it already take a look at the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) design pattern advocated by Apple.

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: I have heard of MVC. I was planning to define a Model for application data but in this case, I am building a 2 level drill down table that is populated with fixed data from a plist. I wasn't sure for a small instance if I should still always follow this?

Comment: Always? Perhaps not but it is a good default pattern to use if you don't have better ideas. Your data has already increased in complexity once. Packaging it away in a Model will hide implementation details and reduce the impact of future data format changes on your views and controllers.